# how to install sql server express 2008 R2 silently by installshield 2010

Tags: installation, installshield, sql-server-2008r2-express

I want to Install sql server express 2008 R2 silently by installshield 2010 but it has problem.
I think the problem is i don't know where place setup file and configuration.ini
would you please say me where i call sql setup file and .ini file?

i add file: http://upload7.ir/images/68528291662297140471.png
and run setup.exe: http://upload7.ir/images/67861031941524497179.jpg

Comment: I test it with another way, with command and it work in cmd prompt. My problem is where I execute this command for install SQL in installsheild 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Run the installation of SQL Server 2008 R2
2. Configure the installation
3. In the “Ready to Install” page, please click “Cancel” to cancel the installation
4. Then we will see a ConfigurationFile.ini in the location provided in the textbox under “Configuration file path:” in “Ready to Install” page.

see details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/d709ce9d-ebcb-4ed5-9c85-0b750be0f88d/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Your link was usefull.I check my ini file but i have a question again.my program need .net 4 and i install .net 4 befor of install sql but i have a problem,the sql during install has error and need .net 3.5.What can i do?

Comment: I should have .net 4 for my app and .net 3.5 for sql?

Comment: Yes, you can download it http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21. By default, SQL will automatically be set. Net 3.5